# Is the Apple SIM pricing comparable to buying a local sim-card?

Tags: cellphones, price, roaming

Apple [launched their SIM](https://www.apple.com/ipad/apple-sim/) product recently, with the description mentioning that:

> When you travel, Apple SIM gives you the flexibility to stay connected in more than 100 countries and territories around the world. So when you reach your destination and want to check your email, find directions, or send a message back home, you can purchase a cellular data plan for the duration of your trip — whether it’s a day, a week, or a month.

This sounds perfect for travel as you no longer have to waste time buying a local sim-card or looking for Wi-Fi. However their website doesn't mention anything about the pricing of their plans in each individual country.

So the questions are:

1. Where can I find the price of using the Apple SIM in each supported country?
2. Is the price generally comparable to getting a local sim-card for data?

Comment: The thing is that Apple does not offer a specific plan, only a SIM card that can be used with several providers. The plans I found when looking into it (e.g. [GigSky](https://applesim.gigsky.com/pricing)) are still (much) more expensive than a local SIM (or even EU roaming prices incidentally) so it's really about convenience and breadth of coverage more than anything else. And the same providers also offer regular plans with a provider-supplied SIM for non-Apple devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apple sim HDSPA prepaid prices in spain:

- 75 Mb to spend in 3 days 10€ (aprox. $11)
- 400 Mb to spend in 7 days 25€ (aprox. $28)
- 800 Mb to spend in 14 days 35€ (aprox. $39)
- 3Gb to spend in 30 days 50€ (aprox. $56)

compared to local prices:

Vodafone ES : 750MB to spend in 15 days 9.99€ (aprox. 11$) Vat included.

Vodafone ES : 1.5GB to spend in 30 days 14.99€ (aprox. 17$) Vat included.

It's thrice the price, i wouldn't get it.

i contrast, i pay 24.90€/mo for 4gb at 4G speed + 100 minutes  of free cell to cell talk.

Comment: Sounds about right but where did you get the price info for the Apple SIM (which provider/country)?

Comment: Coworker got an email from a local Apple products store days ago and i asked him. There are some Apple fan blog posts from Spain stating similar prices.

Comment: 750GB must be 750MB.

Comment: So that's the price to use a Spanish plan in Spain? Does your coworker happen to know which provider(s) are available through the Apple SIM in Spain?

Comment: oops. edited.  @Relaxed , i ithink it's T-mobile or some lesser company related to them, but he doesn't know. the store just listed those prices as the average in the possible providers.  a web blog states that https://applesim.gigsky.com/  will provide to spain too, and their prices are similar to the ones listed.

Comment: **Apple** taking a huge cut? I'm utterly shocked.